# launch chrome app from any browser as http://myChromeAppUrl

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

chrome app

1. is it possible to launch myChrome Application from standard url,
   means:
   http://myWebServer/myChromeApp and it will launch chrome application,
   in same manner as I launch any standard web page ?
2. I tried with chrome web browser to make url http://... to my chrome app folder, but it opened it as standard web page, with-out taking the extensions files: (manifest.js,backgourd.js..) in consideration.

so the issue is to launch chrome app from URL call(http or https), without any install on local PC, or any prompt on client browser PC
it will launched, as standard web page browse

any help ?

Comment: `I tried with chrome web browser to make url http://... to my chrome app folder...` How did you try this? Are you running a local HTTP server?

Comment: The best solution here is probably to use [`webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to redirect `http://myWebServer/myChromeApp` to `chrome-extension://dhehgsfrg...`, if redirects to `chrome-extension://` are allowed.

Comment: how is the syntax of URL to browse directly to chrome-extensions to myChromeApp , from any PC ?  the app will be located under some my web server /chrome-extension://dhehgsfrg... or from chrome webstore , as a web server ?